# Sumar algunos elementos de un array en java

Tags: java

me piden hacer una  funcion en java en la cual el usuario pase por parametros un vector y los indices en los cuales quiere que se haga la suma , es decir si yo le paso un vector t cualquiera y los indices 2 y 5 (suma(t,2,5)) tendria que devolverme la suma de los elementos del vector desde el indice 2 al indice 5.
La sintaxis debe ser la siguiente **suma(int[]vecEnteros, int a , int b){
}**

Comment: Me temo que si no lees [ask] y añades lo que llevas, te van a cerrar la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay que crear un ciclo que sume los rangos de los indices, hay que tener en cuanta que los indices no se salgan del tamaño del vector y que a > b en todos los casos

```
public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [ ] vector = { 2, 7, 4, 7, 15 };
        System.out.println(suma(vector, 2,4));
    }

    public static int suma(int[]vecEnteros, int a , int b){
        try{
        int suma=0;
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            suma+=vecEnteros[i];
        }
        return suma;
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias ahora el codigo funciona a la perfeccion :)